# Find MisMatch rows in same table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
StudentID   StudentID NO
1           111
1           211
1           111
2           444
2           444 
2           444
5           555
5           555
5           NULL
6           66
6           66
6           66
6           66
```

Output
1
5

The output is 1 and 5 because they have different studentIDnos wheareas 2 and 6 have same studentIDnos. We should take care null also. Consider 5

I need a SQL server Query to get this output

Comment: how can a table have 2 columns with same name StudentID?

Comment: One is StudentID and another StudentIDNo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a group by and having clause like this:

```
SELECT studentID
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY studentID
HAVING count(distinct isnull(studentID_NO,1)) > 1
```

It will return every students that have more then 1 studentID_NO

Comment: this I know, Will it take care null?

Comment: Now it will.. added the isnull part @jamir

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO @Table1
    (StudentID, StudentIDNO)
VALUES
    (1, '111'),
    (1, '211'),
    (1, '111'),
    (2, '444'),
    (2, '444'),
    (2, '444'),
    (5, '555'),
    (5, '555'),
    (5, NULL),
    (6, '66'),
    (6, '66'),
    (6, '66'),
    (6, '66')
;

Select T.StudentID from (
select  StudentID, StudentIDNO from @Table1
GRoup by StudentID, StudentIDNO)T
GROUP BY T.StudentID
HAVING COUNT(T.StudentID) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
select StudentID from T
group by StudentID
having count(distinct isnull([StudentID NO], -1)) > 1
```

Assuming -1 is not going to appear

Comment: thanks But will mark sagi answer is correct. Yurs alos correct

Comment: Remember the value in isnull must not appear as a valid value in the table, else null will not be counted as a value